# Convert Spatial Weight Matrix File?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, autoregressive

I want to create a spatially lagged version of my response variable to estimate a spatial autoregressive model in R. To quantify the spatial relationship that exists among the features in my data I have used [Generate Network Spatial Weights-tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/generate-network-spatial-weights.htm) in ArcMap. Basically, this tool defines the feature spatial relationships based on an underlying network structure (a street network in my case). The problem is that output from the Generate Network Spatial Weights-tool is a Spatial Weight Matrix file (.swm), which I don't know how to use in R. I, therefore, wonder if someone knows:

1. Is there any package in R that support .swm files or is there a way to convert the .swm file into a format that is easier to handle in R, such as .gal or .gwt format?
2. Is there any package or function in R that allows me to define the feature spatial relationships based on an underlying network structure similar to the Generate Network Spatial Weights-tool in ArcMap?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recall looking at these .swm files about a decade ago, so I'm hazy on the details, but my memory is that (1) they are in a simple, easily read format; (2) you can figure out that format fairly quickly by looking at the Python source code for the tool that generates these files; and (3) you don't really need to know Python.  Strategically it may be a good idea to use ArcMap to generate these files and read them into R (rather than generating them in R) because that's a good division of labor: let the GIS do the spatial calculations, then hand the ball to R for the analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, whuber. I will have a look at it and see if I can figure it out. I also found out that there actually is a tool in ArcMap that converts .swm files to .dbf files, maybe that will make it easier for me.